# Are accepted answers of score 0 making a topic "answered"?

Tags: support, search

So I was going to search for **unanswered questions with at least one answer** which should be then of score `0` since the topic is unanswered.

According to [advanced search](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching) I thought it should work:

```
closed:no isanswered:no answers:1
```

because:

> isanswered: `yes/true/1` returns only questions that have at least one accepted or positively-scored answer; `no/false/0` returns only questions with **no accepted or positively-scored** answers.

But the query returns accepted answers...

So is something wrong with my query or are such answers not enough to make question "answered" and the documentation is wrong?

p.s. `answers:1+` in this case returns topics with 0 answers...

Comment: Now I think this `or` with marked quote really matters... On the other hand this won't work either: `closed:no isaccepted:no isanswered:no answers:1`

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks again :) fee free to answer ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250626/the-isanswered-search-parameter-documentation-is-incorrect and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250109/the-search-parameter-isanswered-ignores-acceptances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow `isanswered:no` doesn't exclude questions with an accepted answer scored 0.

The following query should give you the desired search results:

```
isanswered:no closed:no hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1

Comment: I suppose it is because the OR operator in `no accepted or positively-scored`, you can add it if you agree.

Comment: @Kuba To me it also looks like that OR is programmed as an exclusive OR and I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: no no, I mean, that makes sense. All topics from my query have accepted answer of score `0` so it fulfills `no accepted or positively-scored` as `0 or 1 -> 1`

Comment: @Kuba Ah OK, didn't read it that way. However I'd expect `isanswered:no` to be the opposite of `isanswered:yes`.

Comment: @Kuba I was reading it as *no [(accepted or positively-scored) answer]*. Whereas you and the search system seem to read it as *(no accepted answer) or (no positively-scored answer)*.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same but then I changed my mind, just after posting the question. Still, not so clean convention imo so worth a topic.